# C search an element in a BST

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BstNode {
    int data;
    struct BstNode* left;
    struct BstNode* right;
} BstNode;

typedef BstNode* BstNodePtr;
typedef BstNode** BstNodePtrPtr;

void Insert(BstNodePtrPtr root, int data);
BstNodePtr createNewNode(int data);
int Search(BstNodePtr root, int data);

void main() {
    BstNodePtr root = NULL;
    Insert(&root, 15);
    Insert(&root, 10);
    Insert(&root, 20);

    if( Search(root, 15) ) {
        printf("%s", "Found");
    } else {
        printf("%s", "Not found");
    }
}

BstNodePtr createNewNode(int data) {
    BstNodePtr newNode = malloc(sizeof(BstNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void Insert(BstNodePtrPtr root, int data) {
    if((*root) == NULL) {
        (*root) = createNewNode(data);
    }
    else if (data <= (*root)->data) {
        Insert(&((*root)->left), data);
    }
    else {
        Insert(&((*root)->right), data);
    }
}

int Search(BstNodePtr root, int data) {
    if(root = NULL) return 0;
    else if(root->data == data) return 1;
    else if(data <= root->data) return Search(root->left, data);
    else return Search(root->right, data);
}
```

If a value is found or not found in a bst, I want to print "found" or "not found", but this code prints nothing. I did not receive error or warning while compiling. I couldn't debug it because while debugging dev c++ suddenly shuts down. I didn't face a problem like this while debugging another code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function **Search(BstNodePtr root, int data)** while comparing with **NULL** you have placed only '=' sign instead of '=='

```
int Search(BstNodePtr root, int data) {
    if(root == NULL) return 0;
    else if(root->data == data) return 1;
    else if(data <= root->data) return Search(root->left, data);
    else return Search(root->right, data);
}
```